# How do I assign a stacklevel to a Warning depending on the caller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, constructor, warnings

I have a Python class that issues a warning inside `__init__()`. It also provides a factory class method for opening and reading a file:

```py
from warnings import warn

class MyWarning(Warning):
    """Warning issued when an invalid name is found."""
    pass

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, names):
        # Simplified; actual code is longer
        if is_invalid(names):
            names = fix_names(names)
            warn(f'{names!r} contains invalid element(s)',
                MyWarning, stacklevel=2)
        self._names = names

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filename):
        with open(filename) as file:
            names = extract_names(file)
        return cls(names)
```

`stacklevel=2` makes the warning refer to the call to `MyClass()` rather than the `warn()` statement itself. This works when user code directly instantiates MyClass. However, when `MyClass.from_file()` issues the warning, `MyWarning` refers to `return cls(names)`, not the user code calling `from_file()`.

How do I ensure that the factory method also issues a warning that points to the caller? Some options I've considered:

1. Add a "hidden" `_stacklevel` parameter to `__init__()`, and instantiate MyClass with `_stacklevel=2` inside `from_file()`.

   - This is super ugly, and exposes internal behavior to the API.
2. Add a "hidden" `_stacklevel` class attribute, and access it inside `__init__()`. Then temporarily modify this attribute in `from_file()`

   - Also super ugly.
3. Add a `_set_names()` method that checks/fixes the names and issues a warning when needed. Then call this method inside the constructor. For `from_file()`, first instantiate MyClass with empty args, then directly call `_set_names()` to ensure that MyWarning points to the caller.

   - Still hacky, and effectively calls `_set_names()` twice when `from_file()` is called.
4. Catch and re-throw the warning, similar to exception chaining.

   - Sounds good, but I have no idea how to do this.

I read the [`warning` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) but it offers little help on safely catching and re-throwing warnings. Converting the warning to an exception using [`warnings.simplefilter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.simplefilter) would interrupt `MyClass()` and force me to call it again.

Comment: For option 3, you could also add an option `validate=True` to `__init__`, such that in `from_file` you can use `validate=False`. Also, I would create a method `_validate_names` instead of `_set_names`.

Comment: **None of the existing solutions are thread-safe.** Honestly, the optimal means of resolving `stacklevel` is to do so dynamically on behalf of the caller by: **(1)** iterating up the call stack (e.g., by calling `sys._getframe()`, which all Python implementations that anyone cares about implements – including PyPy and Brython) and **(2)** computing the distance from you to the closest external caller that is *not* you. That's the `stacklevel` you want – and it's guaranteed to work everywhere without hacky kludges or manual intervention.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch warnings similar to the way you catch exceptions using `warnings.catch_warnings()`:

```
import warnings

class MyWarning(Warning):
    """Warning issued when an invalid name is found."""
    pass

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, names):
        # Simplified; actual code is longer
        if is_invalid(names):
            names = fix_names(names)
            warn(f'{names!r} contains invalid element(s)',
                MyWarning, stacklevel=2)
        self._names = names

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, filename):
        with open(filename) as file:
            names = extract_names(file)
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as cx_manager:
            inst = cls(names)

        #re-report warnings with the stack-level we want
        for warning in cx_manager:
            warnings.warn(warning.message, warning.category, stacklevel=2)

        return inst
```

Just keep in mind the following note from the documentation of `warnings.catch_warnings()`:

> Note The catch_warnings manager works by replacing and then later restoring the module’s `showwarning()` function and internal list of filter specifications. This means the context manager is modifying global state and therefore is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

David is right, `warnings.catch_warnings(record=True)` is probably what you want. Though I would write it as a function decorator instead:

```
def reissue_warnings(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        with warnings.catch_warnings(record = True) as warning_list:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        for warning in warning_list:
            warnings.warn(warning.message, warning.category, stacklevel = 2)
        return result
    return inner
```

And then in your example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, names):
        # ...

    @classmethod
    @reissue_warnings
    def from_file(cls, filename):
        with open(filename) as file:
            names = extract_names(file)
        return cls(names)

inst = MyClass(['some', 'names'])   # 58: MyWarning: ['some', 'names'] contains invalid element(s)
inst = MyClass.from_file('example') # 59: MyWarning: ['example'] contains invalid element(s)
```

This way also allows you to cleanly collect and reissue warnings across multiple functions as well:

```
class Test:
    def a(self):
        warnings.warn("This is a warning issued from a()")
        
    @reissue_warnings
    def b(self):
        self.a()
    
    @reissue_warnings
    def c(self):
        warnings.warn("This is a warning issued from c()")
        self.b()
        
    @reissue_warnings
    def d(self):
        self.c()
        
test = Test()
test.d() # Line 59
# 59: UserWarning: This is a warning issued from c()
# 59: UserWarning: This is a warning issued from a()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to give you stack level based on the list of modules, above which the user code is situated.

Useful if you just know the names of modules in your library, but are not sure from which of the modules exactly the function that issues the warning will be called.

```py
def get_warning_stack_level(module_filenames: Union[str, List[str]]) -> int:
    """Calculate the stack level for warnings issued from a library.

    Returns the number of stack frames between the top-most module from the given list
    occurring in the call stack and the caller of the function.

    This is used to provide the appropriate stack level to warnings.warn or
    warnings.warn_explicit so that the warning appears in user code rather
    than in the library itself.

    The calculation is based on the system call stack.

    Args:
        module_filenames: The filenames of possible top-most modules before which the
            user code is situated. If a single filename is provided, it is wrapped
            in a list. May or may not contain the ".py" extension.

    Returns:
        The stack level to be used in warnings.warn or warnings.warn_explicit.

    Raises:
        ValueError: If none of the modules in the provided sequence have been found
            in the stack.
    """

    # Wrap single filename in a list
    if isinstance(module_filenames, str):
        module_filenames = [module_filenames]

    # Remove '.py' extension from filenames
    module_filenames = [f[:-3] if f.endswith(".py") else f for f in module_filenames]

    # Append '.py' to filenames
    module_filenames += [f"{f}.py" for f in module_filenames]

    # Make tuple of filenames
    module_filenames = tuple(module_filenames)

    # Get filenames from stack
    stack_filenames = []
    top_frame = sys._getframe()
    while top_frame is not None:
        stack_filenames.append(top_frame.f_code.co_filename)
        top_frame = top_frame.f_back

    # Find top-most module filename in the stack
    try:
        top_most_index = next(
            i
            for i, v in enumerate(reversed(stack_filenames))
            if v.endswith(module_filenames)
        )
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError(
            "None of the modules in the provided sequence have been found "
            "in the stack."
        )

    # Calculate stack level
    return len(stack_filenames) - top_most_index
```